# Using Boost with getters and setters?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to serialize a class I don't have write access to. I.e., I can't change the source file nor the header file. Furthermore, most fields are private and are accessed through getter and setter functions.

Can anyone tell me whether it is a good idea (or not) to just create different functions for saving and loading (as explained in the [boost tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html))...

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, gps_position &g, const unsigned int version) const
{
    // note, version is always the latest when saving
    ar  & g.deg;
    ar  & g.min;
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, gps_position &g, const unsigned int version)
{
    if(version > 0)
        ar & g.deg;
        ar & g.min;
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

... and there use the public functions:

```
ar & g.getDeg();
```

instead of

```
ar & g.deg;
```

(similar for setter)?? I'm really new into c++ and serialization and I'm very thankful for any hints!

best, alex

edit: added link to boost tutorial

Comment: You should definitely link to the tutorial you are referring to.

Comment: Really, I don't see how this could be any kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, gps_position &g, const unsigned int version)
{
    if(version > 0)
    {
        int d = 0;
        ar & d;
        g.setDeg(d);
        int m = 0;
        ar & m;
        g.setMin(m);
    }
}
```

something like this. declare variable -> read from archive -> set to member by calling setter function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the tutorial that the OP is talking about:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

I have found that using the split functions is sometimes necessary and not a bad idea when it is necessary.  Using the single `void serialize(...)` function is really convenient, but I've had to split them up when the class I am trying to serialize can't be changed (like what you are encountering).  I definitely wouldn't shy away from splitting `void serialize(...)` into `void save(...)` and `void load(...)` if that's what it is going to take.  If memory serves me right, I had to split into 2 functions cos I `__gnu_cxx::hash_map` support wasn't very good at one point several years ago, so I did some hack around it to get the data serialized.

The [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) gets you going, but it is a little lacking and I run into some kind of difficulty every time I use Boost.Serialization.  It's a convenient library to use though.